# How to use onClick in antd table to get target value?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, antd, expandable-table

I have an `antd` table, where there is an expandable row. I want to render data based on the row that I click as each row has a unique code. How do I get the target value of the row so as to filter data accordingly?

```
<Table
  components={components}
  bordered
  dataSource={dataSource}
  columns={tableColumns}
  expandable={{ expandedRowRender,
  onClick: (e) =>findId(+e.target.value),
}}
```

Do I use onRow? Not sure how `onClick` is used in `antD` table or an expandable table. I've also got

```
expandRowByClick: true,
```

enabled in the expandable. So I have two questions

1. How can I expand the table by clicking only one particular cell
2. When expanded, how can I capture the clicked row so that I can render data accordingly to the expanded table?

Answer (score 3):

Same as onRow, onHeaderRow, onCell, onHeaderCell

```
   <Table
  onRow={(record, rowIndex) => {
    return {
      onClick: event => { 
         console.log(record)
      }, // click row
      onDoubleClick: event => {}, // double click row
      onContextMenu: event => {}, // right button click row
      onMouseEnter: event => {}, // mouse enter row
      onMouseLeave: event => {}, // mouse leave row
    };
  }}
  onHeaderRow={(columns, index) => {
    return {
      onClick: () => {}, // click header row
    };
  }}
/>
```

if you want to click a button :

```
<Column
        title="title"
        dataIndex="cdcName"
        key="cdcName"
        render={(text, record)=><button onClick={(e)=> console.log(e)}>{record?.cdcName}</button>}
    />
```

in onExpand :

```
 <Table
       
        onExpandedRowsChange={(expandedRows)=>{ }}
        expandedRowRender={row => <span>hello</span>}
        expandRowByClick
        onExpand={(expanded, record)=>{
        var keys = [];
        if(expanded){
            keys.push(record.id); // I have set my record.id as row key. Check the documentation for more details.
        }
    
        this.setState({expandedRowKeys: keys});
    }}
    />
```

Comment: I tried this, but somehow I'm not receiving the target value on the onClick?

Comment: could 'nt you get the record?

Comment: No, I'm not able to. Could you kindly help? I'm new to react

Comment: I don't know why you can not get the recorded of a row

Comment: pay attention you just can get the recorded not the target value

Comment: Hi, thank you so much.. it worked, I am able to get the recorded value. I have another question.. can onRow be used inside expandable? Because I am getting an error when I try to pass it to the expandedRowRender method

Comment: Hi. I edited my answer again and add about onExpandedRowsChange .hope to helps you.

Comment: check https://codesandbox.io/embed/2opjp3lnrp?fontsize=14

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I have one last question, I'd like to set the coloumnWidth of the expandable icon, but I'm not able to set it in expandable={ )

Answer (score 0):

you have to set an action to get the record data of a row in a column.

for exemple :

```
    const tableColumns =  [
          { title: "id", dataIndex: "id", key: "id", sorter: true },
          {
            title: "Description",
            dataIndex: "description",
            key: "description",
            sorter: true
          },
          {
            title: "Action",
            dataIndex: "id",
            key: "id",
            align: "center",
            render: (text, record, index) => {
              return (
                
                  <Button
                    icon={<BsPencil />}
                    id={record.id}
                    onClick={e => console.log(e, record)}
           //record is the row data
                    size="large"
                    
                  />
    
                 
          
              );
            }
          }
        ];
    
    
    <Table
      components={components}
      // add this
      rowKey={(record) => record.id} 
      bordered
      dataSource={dataSource}
      columns={tableColumns}
      expandable={{ expandedRowRender,
      onClick: (e) =>findId(+e.target.value),
    }}
```

Comment: Hi, in the <Table> tag, the onClick goes to findId? I tried doing it this way but there's some issue. If I have to create a separate button inside the table, then how do I add an onClick to that to capture the record details?

Comment: you don't add the button inside the table, you add it inside each row of the table so the onClick can get the record of each row